# Which table contains User's email id in Hana Database?

Tags: hana

I am not seeing user's email-id column in public.users view in HANA database. In which table/view it is present?

Comment: Why do you think there should be an email address in `public.users` view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from SAP help portal.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.05/en-US/cd81e47ddc1e41a5a56a817fcc7b497f.html

It is in **USER_PARAMETERS**.